# Problem solving with mass in terms of logs and exponentials

Tags: logarithms

I've just been accepted to take my PHD in chemical engineering in Melbourne next year. Some how I have gone from the age of 17 with out taking too many extra maths classes and so at the moment (I'm 26) I am trying to teach myself some logarithms and exponentials. Everything is going well so far, I am understanding the laws and piecing them together. Every now and then I come across a question which throws me, one where I am unsure of my methodology, but I'm sure this is where the learning happens.

For example, I just found this question in a textbook:

The mass xkg of a radio-active substance remaining in a sample t days after starting timing is given by the equation x = 4e^-0.2t.

If it asks me to find the mass at the start of the timing, I'm quite certain I just remove the -0.2t exponential right?

Would x = 4ekg be a sufficient answer?

Comment: Though being left with simply 4e would involve Euler's constant right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the mass is $4e^{-0.2t}$  When you substitute in $t=0$ to get the beginning mass, this becomes $4e^0$.  As $e^0=1$, this is $4$, not $4e$

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. What kind of method could I use in order to find the mass left after 5 years, if mass left t days after starting timing is not specified?

Comment: What information do you have in that case?  Without such an equation as you gave in the original question, you have no information to know the mass left

Comment: Following on from the first question I am just asked to 'find the mass left after 5 years'

Comment: In this case the timing is the same, so just putting 5 years in the time variable with the appropriate units ($5*(number of days in a year)$) will give you the answer, the thing is, for any time that function gives you the mass at that specific time $(t)$

Comment: Great thanks this is very helpful. So just 4e^5 kg *365

Comment: Please be more careful.  As I commented on your other question, this should read as $4e^5 \cdot 365 \approx 216683$ kg.  You lost putting the $365$ in the exponent, changed $0.2$ to $5$, as well as the minus sign in the exponent.  It should be $4e^{(-0.2 \cdot 365)}\approx 8\cdot 10^{-32}$

Comment: But how could it be the latter, when -0.2 is referred to as "t days" and not 5? 
I'm really sorry if I'm annoying you, but I'm annoying myself because I don't understand. 

I can see that the answer is 216683kg, but I can't see the parity between this and 8.10^-32 kg

Comment: The exponent needs the factor $-0.2$. After five years, it should be $e^{-0.2 \cdot 5 \cdot 365}$  I lost the $5$.  The $t$ is in the exponent and is measured in days.

Answer (score 1):

For the initial mass you only need to go back to when the timing began, so setting t=0 should give you the answer. $$x_0=4e^0=4$$